# undefined reference to pthread_create and pthread_join

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linker-errors

I am trying to build my program but keep getting the same error messages:

```
undefined reference to pthread_create  
undefined reference to pthread_join
```

I have included pthread.h and in my makefile im compiling with `-pthread`.

```
int threadAmount = strtol(nrthr, NULL, 0);
    threadAmount--;

    if(threadAmount > 0){
        pthread_t tids[threadAmount];

        for(int i = 0;i < threadAmount; i++){
            pthread_attr_t attr;
            pthread_attr_init(&attr);
            pthread_create(&tids[i],&attr,search,&t1);
        }

        for(int i = 0;i < threadAmount; i++){
            pthread_join(tids[i],NULL);
        }
    }
```

It's where I'm calling create and join where it's complaining. What could be the problem?

The makefile used to build:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -pthread -std=gnu11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wunused -Wold-style-definition -Wundef -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wunreachable-code

all: mfind

list.o: list.c list.h
    $(CC) -c list.c $(CFLAGS)

mfind.o: mfind.c list.h
    $(CC) -c mfind.c $(CFLAGS) 

mfind: mfind.o list.o
    $(CC) mfind.o list.o -o mfind

clean:
    rm -f *.o mfind
```

`mfind` is the main program and `list.c` is an implemented list.

Comment: how exactly are you building? Edit your question and add that info. This is a linker error, the pthread library isn't getting linked in somehow

Comment: i added in my makefile, is that sufficient? @yano

Comment: order matters when you link. Try removing `-pthread` from `CFLAGS` and doing `$(CC) mfind.o list.o -pthread -o mfind`. Generally there are compiler flags (your CFLAGS) and linker flags (`-pthread` would go in the linker flags variable, compiler shouldn't need that). I'm no makefile expert, however.

Comment: sweet! In general if `codeA.o` calls a function in `codeB.o`, then you must link with `codeA.o` _before_ `codeB.o` in the linker command .. that's been my experience anyway.

Comment: `-pthread` can affect both preprocessor macros and linking, so it's best to just always specify it to the "gcc" driver program.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> list.o: list.c list.h
>     $(CC) -c list.c $(CFLAGS)
>
> mfind.o: mfind.c list.h
>     $(CC) -c mfind.c $(CFLAGS) 
>
> mfind: mfind.o list.o
>     $(CC) mfind.o list.o -o mfind
> ```

It looks like some of your recipes are missing `CFLAGS`, which includes the option `-pthread`. I believe it should be:

```
list.o: list.c list.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c list.c

mfind.o: mfind.c list.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c mfind.c

mfind: mfind.o list.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) mfind.o list.o -o mfind

...
```

Its OK to `CFLAGS` to the output artifact. In fact, you should use the same `CFLAGS` (and `CXXFLAGS`) when the compiler driver drives link. You should also always use the compiler driver because it takes care of turning options, like `-pthread`, `-fopenmp` and `-fsanitize=undefined`, into the proper options and libraries for the linker.

If interested, here are the default rule used with GNUmake: [Catalogue of Built-In Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html). Notice the recipe for `*.c` files includes `CFLAGS`:

> **Compiling C programs**
>
> `n.o` is made automatically from `n.c` with a recipe of the form `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c`.

If you use the following from the GNU Make manual, then you should also add `-pthread` to `LDFLAGS`. But I recommend you follow what the compiler guys tell us, and that is to drive link through the compiler driver.

> **Linking a single object file**
>
> `n` is made automatically from `n.o` by running the linker (usually
>   called `ld`) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)`.

Answer (score 1):

`-pthread` doesn't belong in `CFLAGS`. As you already found, the libraries that are needed must be at the end of the command line options after all the object files. You need to put `-pthread` in `LDLIBS` since you have a makefile.

From https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html:

> LDLIBS
>
> Library flags or names given to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker, ‘ld’. LOADLIBES is a deprecated (but still supported) alternative to LDLIBS. Non-library linker flags, such as -L, should go in the LDFLAGS variable.

Comment: As I understand things, `-pthread` belongs in both `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`. The compiler driver will see it, and add `-D_REENTRANT` (and other options) as required. It will also invoke the linker with the proper flags and libraries when the compiler drivers link.

Comment: "The compiler driver will see it, and add -D_REENTRANT (and other options) as required. It will also invoke the linker with the proper flags and libraries when the compiler drivers link" - that may have been true for ancient C libraries in order to generate thread code but not anymore. It doesn't hurt to have `-pthread` in both `CFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` but not required to have it in CFLAGS.